AudioManager.setStreamVolume not functioning on Android 14 updated phone
I recently updated my phone's software to One UI 6 on Android 14 and noticed that the functionality to change the volume of my Alarm apps has stopped working. The volume is always at maximum now. Below is the exact code I am using that used to work before the OS upgrade:
val audioManager = requireContext().getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
binding.soundCard.volumeBar.valueTo = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
binding.soundCard.volumeBar.addOnChangeListener { _, value, _ ->
       audioManager.setStreamVolume(
                AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
                value.toInt(),
                AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE
       )
}

*edit :
I changed the flag to FLAG_SHOW_UI, and it seems the code is adjusting the stream volume correctly. But, it appears that the MediaPlayer is not following its specified usage stream channel, as shown in the code below::
mediaPlayer.apply {
            setAudioAttributes(
                AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build()
            )
            setDataSource(requireContext(), Uri.parse(alarm.ringtoneUri))
            prepare()
            start()
        }

The only thing I managed to test was to try older versions and check the Git history to see if I changed anything that caused this error. I noticed the issue is present in older versions, indicating it originated from the Android 14 upgrade. I currently do not have access to another Android 14 device, and for some reason, I am unable to run an emulator to test it.
